# setfacl: x.txt: Operation not supported

Tags: linux, access-control-list

What I did and what it did:

```
> getfacl  x.txt 
# file: x.txt
# owner: cwhii
# group: cwhii
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--

> groups
cwhii adm dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin admin sambashare
> setfacl --modify=g:adm:rw x.txt
setfacl: x.txt: Operation not supported
> uname -a
Linux road 2.6.31-19-generic #56-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 28 01:26:53 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux
```

What I expected was an additional access control entry on x.txt without an error message.

Comment: i checked tune2fs and it said that the defaults include xattrs and acl but I got the same response. Is it possible that I still need to add acl?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This sounds like the default mount behavior is not allowing ACLs on the filesystem.  getfacl will report the normal filesystem permissions without error, but setfacl is unable to operate because the filesystem is mounted without the ACL option.

You can add this in /etc/fstab or by modifying your filesystem options.

Assuming you have the /home filesystem on /dev/sda, you can do the following:

Modify Filesystem method:

> sudo /sbin/tune2fs -o +acl /dev/sda

Modify /etc/fstab method:

> /dev/sda /home ext3 defaults,acl 1 2

Using either method, the filesystem has to be remounted to take effect.  You can accomplish this by rebooting, or by running

> sudo /bin/mount -o remount /home

Comment: ACLs are disabled by default due to performance reasons.