# Setfacl: Operation not supported

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, access-control-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [setfacl: x.txt: Operation not supported](https://serverfault.com/questions/110250/setfacl-x-txt-operation-not-supported)

I am trying to do:

```
setfacl -m d:u:apache:rw /etc/asterisk/additional/
```

but getting:

```
setfacl: /etc/asterisk/additional/: Operation not supported
```

my `/etc/fstab` looks like this:

```
LABEL=/     /           ext4    defaults,noatime  1   1
tmpfs       /dev/shm    tmpfs   defaults        0   0
devpts      /dev/pts    devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0   0
sysfs       /sys        sysfs   defaults        0   0
proc        /proc   proc    defaults        0   0
/dev/sda3   none    swap    sw,comment=cloudconfig  0   0
```

Can someone help me please? I tried what others  tried and ended up screwing my server and had reinstall. Now I'm back at this step and don't wanna do the same mistake. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding ',acl' after noatime. Then reboot or just invoke `mount -o remount /`.

Comment: No need to reboot, just `mount -o remount /`.